# What does print()'s `flush` do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a boolean optional argument to the `print()` function `flush` which defaults to False.

The documentation says it is to forcibly flush the stream.

I don't understand the concept of flushing. What is flushing here? What is flushing of stream?

Comment: I believe this forces all of the data to be printed to the console to immediately be "flushed" to the actual console and leave the pending print buffer

Comment: @ChristianStewart I can't get the concept. Can you point me a practical example?

Comment: @ChristianStewart: I am not sure that is always the case, I remember cases where you needed to have a newline to 'autoflush'. This probably depends on the underlying OS.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Normally output to a file or the console is buffered, with text output at least until you print a newline. The flush makes sure that any output that is buffered goes to the destination.

I do use it e.g. when I make a user prompt like `Do you want to continue (Y/n):`, before getting the input.

This can be simulated (on Ubuntu 12.4 using Python 2.7):

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
from time import sleep

fp = sys.stdout
print('Do you want to continue (Y/n): ', end='')
# fp.flush()
sleep(5)
```

If you run this, you will see that the prompt string does not show up until the sleep ends and the program exits. If you uncomment the line with flush, you will see the prompt and then have to wait 5 seconds for the program to finish

Comment: I really need an example how it differs from the default.

Comment: Hope this helps you @Yuushi's explanation has more detail than mine, try to see if that helps you as well.

Comment: OK! I got the concept. I made a more interactive script to demonstrate this:  https://gist.github.com/santosh/5235922

Answer (score 46):

There are a couple of things to understand here. One is the difference between buffered I/O and unbuffered I/O. The concept is fairly simple - for buffered I/O, there is an internal buffer which is kept. Only when that buffer is full (or some other event happens, such as it reaches a newline) is the output "flushed". With unbuffered I/O, whenever a call is made to output something, it will do this, 1 character at a time.

Most I/O functions fall into the buffered category, mainly for performance reasons: it's a lot faster to write chunks at a time (all I/O functions eventually get down to syscalls of some description, which are expensive.)

`flush` lets you manually choose when you want this internal buffer to be written - a call to flush will write any characters in the buffer. Generally, this isn't needed, because the stream will handle this itself. However, there may be situations when you want to make sure something is output before you continue - this is where you'd use a call to `flush()`.

Answer (score 6):

**Two perfect answers we have here,**

*Anthon* made it very clear to understand, Basically, the print line technically does not run *(print)* until the next line has finished.

> Technically the line does run it just stays unbuffered until the
> next line has finished running.

This might cause a bug for some people who uses the `sleep` function after running a `print` function expecting to see it prints before the `sleep` function started.

*So why am I adding another answer?*

**The Future Has Arrived And I Would Like To Take The Time And Update You With It:**

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

*First of all, I believe this was an inside joke meant to show an error: Future is not defined ^_^*

---

I'm looking at *PyCharm's* documentation right now and it looks like they added a flush method built inside the print function itself, **Take a look at this:**

```
def print(self, *args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None): # known special case of print
"""
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
Optional keyword arguments:
file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
"""
pass
```

[image]

---

**So we might be able to use:** (Not sure if the usage order of the parameters should be the same)

```
from __present__ import print_function

from time import sleep

print('Hello World', flush=True)

sleep(5)
```

**Or This:**

```
print('Hello World', file=sys.stdout , flush=True)
```

**As Anthon said:**

> If you run this, you will see that the prompt string does not show up
> until the sleep ends and the program exits. If you uncomment the line
> with flush, you will see the prompt and then have to wait 5 seconds
> for the program to finish

**So let's just convert that to our current situation:**

If you run this, you will see the prompt and then have to wait 5 seconds
for the program to finish, If you change the line
with flush to `flush=False`, you will see that the prompt string does not show up
until the sleep ends and the program exits.

Comment: BTW The documentation came from PyCharm buildins.py file.
I am aware of the fact `flush` is not a valid argument that `print` is accepting.
Please test and let me know so I can update my answer to match the correct status of the present.

Comment: I've never seen a more useless and wrong answer than yours.  He was using `from __future__ import print_function` because of Python 2.   Pycharm can't "add" anything, it's simply a documentation from python.org.  `flush` is not a method, it's a parameter.   
 You don't need `from __present__ import print_function` in Python 3.  This answer should be removed.

Answer (score 6):

A practical example to understand `print()` with and without the `flush` parameter:

```py
import time

for i in range(5):
    print(i, end=" ", flush=True)  # Print numbers as soon as they are generated
    # print(i, end=" ", flush=False)  # Print everything together at the end
    time.sleep(0.5)

print("end")
```

You can comment/uncomment the `print` lines to check how this affects the way the output is produced.

This is similar to the accepted answer, just a bit simpler and for Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Might be relevant to someone:

If you are using `cron` and don't see the output, if you are using print statements(not good practice), it might be because of the print is buffered. If you do `print("statement", flush=True)` then the `log` file will give the statement before the buffer is full/flushed automatically or the program ends.