# Display a countdown for the python sleep function

Tags: python, time, sleep, stopwatch, countdowntimer

I am using time.sleep(10) in my program. Can display the countdown in the shell when I run my program?

```
>>>run_my_program()
tasks done, now sleeping for 10 seconds
```

and then I want it to do 10,9,8,7....

is this possible?

Comment: Thank you for all the wonderful answers.

Comment: related: [countdown using using Tkinter, or Gtk, or Twisted or Asyncio event loops](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

you could always do

```
#do some stuff
print 'tasks done, now sleeping for 10 seconds'
for i in xrange(10,0,-1):
    time.sleep(1)
    print i
```

This snippet has the slightly annoying feature that each number gets printed out on a newline.  To avoid this, you can

```
import sys
import time
for i in xrange(10,0,-1):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i)+' ')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: thanks, this is great. you have just a small mistake which I fixed.

    time.sleep(i)

should be 

    time.sleep(1)

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is fixed for the answer.

Comment: If you're getting ```NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined``` use `range` instead. It was renamed in Python 3.

Answer (score 31):

This is the best way to display a timer in the console for Python 3.x:

```
import time
import sys

for remaining in range(10, 0, -1):
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

sys.stdout.write("\rComplete!            \n")
```

This writes over the previous line on each cycle.

Answer (score 19):

A simple solution that clears the last number from the console:

```
import time

for i in range(10,0,-1):
    print(f"{i}", end="\r", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

By default, the print function sets `end="\n"` which means subsequent calls to print will be printed on a new line. You can change this to `end="\r"` to replace the output after each call. ([How does carriage return "\r" work in python](https://www.codespeedy.com/how-does-carriage-return-work-in-python/)).

Here `f"{i}"` is for printing single digit only. You can modify it based on number of digits.
e.g. Here it will work for two digits by just adding one space as a postfix- `f"{i} "`

Also, using `flush` means you don't have to worry about buffering issues. ([What does print()'s `flush` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608229/what-does-prints-flush-do))

This is how it looks:

[image: countdown]

Comment: This great, however if you input a large number, say 1200, it will end up printing e.g. 8790 instead of 0879 or 879, any way to fix this?

Comment: Oris, Updated the answer as per your comment.

Comment: Change the "print(f("{i}..." for this line `print("{:2d}".format(i), end="\r", flush=True)` Or I will add an edit below this answer

Comment: An alternative is to print another line prior to clear it, such as `print('\r', ' '*100, end='')`

Answer (score 8):

You can do a countdown function like:

```
import sys
import time

def countdown(t, step=1, msg='sleeping'):  # in seconds
    pad_str = ' ' * len('%d' % step)
    for i in range(t, 0, -step):
        print '%s for the next %d seconds %s\r' % (msg, i, pad_str),
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(step)
    print 'Done %s for %d seconds!  %s' % (msg, t, pad_str)
```

The carriage return `\r` and the comma `,` will keep the print in the same line (avoiding one line for each countdown value)

As the number of seconds decreases, the pad_str will ensure the last line is overwritten with spaces instead of leaving the last character(s) behind as the output shortens.

The final print overwrites the last status message with a done message and increments the output line, so there is evidence of the delay.

Comment: To prevent a new line inserted every second in the countdown, the statement `print '%s for the next %d seconds %s\r' % (msg, i, pad_str),` should be changed to `sys.stdout.write( '%s for the next %d seconds %s\r' % (msg, i, pad_str),)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one I did:

```
import time
a = input("How long is the countdown?")
while a != 0:
    print a
    time.sleep(1)
    a = a-1
```

At the end if you and an else you can put an alarm or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

`time.sleep()` may return earlier if the sleep is interrupted by a signal or later (depends on the scheduling of other processes/threads by OS/the interpreter).

To improve accuracy over multiple iterations, to avoid drift for large number of iterations, the countdown may be locked with the clock:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time

for i in reversed(range(1, 1001)):
    time.sleep(1 - time.time() % 1) # sleep until a whole second boundary
    sys.stderr.write('\r%4d' % i)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is something that I've learned at one of my first python lessons, we played with ["/","-","|","\","|"] but the principle is the same:

```
import time

for i in reversed(range(0, 10)):
    time.sleep(1)
    print "%s\r" %i,
```

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way, without reinventing the wheel, is to use [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm), which automatically displays a progress bar:

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

for _ in tqdm(range(10)):
    sleep(1)
```

Optionally, you can then modify the display of the loading bar as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just write a loop that prints 10 minus the iteration counter, then have it sleep 1 second each iteration and run for 10 iterations.  Or, to be even more flexible:

```
def printer(v):
    print v
def countdown_timer(duration, step=1, output_function=printer,
                    prompt='Waiting {duration} seconds.'):
    output_function(prompt.format(duration=duration))
    for i in xrange(duration/step):
        output_function(duration - step * i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is subsecond precise:

```
    print()
    _k = 0.5  # ensure k != _k first time round (as k will be integer)
    print('Starting in ')
    while _k > 0:
        k = round(event_timestamp - time())
        if k != _k:
            print(f'\r{k} ', end='', flush=True)
            _k = k
        sleep(0.1)

    print('boom')
```

Notice the trailing space in `f'\r{k} '`.  So if we go from `100` to `99` or `10` to `9` it clears the second digit.

Also it doesn't require `import sys`.

`sleep(0.0003)` if you want millisecond precision.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't limit yourself to sleep, then (courtesy [automatetheboringstuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter20/)), pyautogui has a nifty countdown function:

```
import pyautogui
print('Starting in ', end=''); pyautogui.countdown(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help

```
    import turtle
    for i in range(10):
        t2 = turtle.Turtle()
        t2.hideturtle()
        t2.penup()
        t2.goto(0,0)
        t2.write(i,font=("Arial", 16, "normal"))
        i-=1
        sleep(1)
        t2.clear()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).