# while loop timer to two decimal places errors

Tags: timer, python-3.4

how do I keep the output to two decimal places

no decimal places:

```
 import time
 print ("60 SECOND TIMER")
 run = input('click ENTER to run')
 secs=0
 while secs < 60:
      print(60 - secs)
      time.sleep(1)
      secs = secs+1
```

two decimal places:

```
 import time
 print ("60 SECOND TIMER")
 run = input('click ENTER to run')
 secs=0
 while secs < 60:
      print(60 - secs)
      time.sleep(0.01)
      secs = secs+0.01
```

Quick note: two decimal places starts going mad (ends up with 8 or 9 decimal places

Comment: I see that Python has a [round() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round). Does that help?

Comment: Was that a comment to me or an addition to your question? If the latter, then please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: thanks for the info, andrew. could you insert the round function, as i tried and it did nothing (I fixed the other comment)

Comment: You should again edit your question to add on how you've tried using `round`, e.g. "I tried `print(round(60 - secs, 2)` and it still showed more than two decimal places." P.S. If you start a comment with "@AndrewMorton" then I will be notified.

Comment: ...oops... `print(round(60 - secs, 2))`

Comment: If that solved it for you, please let us know and I'll make my suggestion into an answer for you.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It works, but the sleep command needs to be 10x shorter to count accurately

Comment: @AndrewMorton scratch that, runs in command prompt without needing to be shorter. plz publish your method as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function like this:

```
print(round(60 - secs, 2))
```

to output the remaining time to two decimal places.

Incidentally, printing it every 10 ms may be a bit optimistic considering that your display is probably only updated 60 times a second, i.e. at 16.67 ms intervals.

Comment: `secs` is misleading here. `round()` may help to hide the floating-point error due to `+=.01` but it can't help to sync. `secs` with the actual time. `time.sleep(0.01)` may sleep both less and more than 10ms. After several iterations `secs += .01` won't reflect the actual time even if the computation were exact.

Answer (score 0):

try [`time.sleep(.01 - timer() % .01)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28369952/4279), to lock the sleep with the `timer()`. Though it won't help if either `time.sleep()` or `timer()` do not support 10ms granularity. It may also depend on how Python interpreter switches between threads (GIL acquire/release) and OS scheduler (how busy the system is and how fast OS can switch between processes/threads).

To pause for a short duration, you could try a busy loop instead:

```
from time import monotonic as timer

deadline = timer() + .01
while timer() < deadline:
    pass
```

For example, to do something every 10ms for a minute using `time.sleep()` would probably fail:

```
import time
from time import monotonic as timer

now = timer()
deadline = now + 60 # a minute
while now < deadline: # do something until the deadline
     time.sleep(.01 - timer() % .01) # sleep until 10ms boundary
     now = timer()
     print("%.06f" % (deadline - now,))
```

but the solution based on a busy loop should be more precise:

```
import time
from time import monotonic as timer

dt = .01 # 10ms
time.sleep(dt - timer() % dt)  
deadline = now = timer()    
outer_deadline = now + 60 # a minute
while now < outer_deadline: # do something until the deadline
     print("%.06f" % (outer_deadline - now,))

     # pause until the next 10ms boundary
     deadline += dt
     while now < deadline:
         now = timer()
```

Comment: could you edit to show where the busy loop would fit into the code

Comment: @JamesTMP: I've added complete examples