# Python: outputs order

Tags: python, output

I would like to know the logic behind the order of the outputs in Python 3.
For example:

**test.py**:

```
import sys
print("my stdout", file=sys.stdout)
print("my stderr", file=sys.stderr)
```

I want both outputs in the same file.

I run the code with this command:

```
python3 test.py 1>all_outputs.txt2>&1
```

I was expecting to obtain the following output:

**all_outputs.txt**:

```
my stdout
my stderr
```

But the result in:

```
my stderr
my stdout
```

So why did the error come in first ?

Comment: It probably has to do with buffering.  Try adding `flush=True` to your `print`s.

Comment: It worked whe I added it to the first print statement. Could you tell me what is flush ? Explain a little bit please

Comment: [What does print()'s `flush` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608229/what-does-prints-flush-do)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Patrick-Haugh in the comments to include `flush=True` parameter to `print()` functions, and borrowing the bash syntax from answer in [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash):

```
import sys
print("my stdout", file=sys.stdout, flush=True)
print("my stderr", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
```

then:

```
$ python3 test.py > all_outputs.txt 2>&1
$ cat all_outputs.txt 
my stdout
my stderr
```