# printing and writing out a generator object

Tags: python, generator

Trying to incorporate a generator object into my code but some how its not working correctly.

```
def get_data():
    data = some_api_call
    result = data.json()
    return result
```

result looks like like this, where each {} is on new line:

```
{u'bytes_out': 1052.0, u'host': u'abc.com'}
{u'bytes_out': 52.0, u'host': u'def.com'}
{u'bytes_out': 5558.0, u'host': u'xya.com'}
...


def write_to_file(line):
    #replacing the write statement with a print for testing
    print(line)

def read_report(data):
    for line in data:
        yield line

def main():
    alldata = get_data()
    write_to_file(read_report(alldata))
```

My expectation here is that it should print out:

```
{u'bytes_out': 1052.0, u'host': u'abc.com'}
{u'bytes_out': 52.0, u'host': u'def.com'}
{u'bytes_out': 5558.0, u'host': u'xya.com'}
```

but what im getting back is :

```
<generator object read_report at 0x7fca02462a00>
```

not sure what I'm missing here

*** EDIT - fixed I was using it incorrectly

```
def main():
    all_data = get_data()
    for line in read_report(all_data)
        print(line)
```

Comment: `read_report` returns a generator. Why are you surprised?

Comment: While `print` will call `str` on its argument for you, `generator.__str__` doesn't build a string by iterating over the instance; it returns a generic representation without any iteration.

Comment: @DYZ because I incorrectly thought that it would print out 1 line of the generator object  what do I need to do to get the desired outcome?

Comment: An iterator is something you can for loop over. This generator is essentially an iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also print directly from a generator:

```
gen = range(1,10)
print(*gen, flush=True)
#out: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

---

so for your case:

```
print(*read_report(all_data), flush=True)
```

Comment: neat, whats the flush do?

Comment: Essentially it forces a print from the buffer. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608229/what-does-prints-flush-do In your case it might not even be necessary, try it without the flush.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of using a generator, as you have to generate the entire sequence in memory before `print` can being.

Comment: @chepner that is True, but in his example he uses it for printing only anyway.

Comment: So? You can print the output line-by-line without reading every line into memory first.