# No delay when required

Tags: python, time

I want to create a function which prints every character of a string with a small time break. I want them to print all the characters in the same line, so I use `end`. It is printing all of them in same line but there is a small delay in start and then it print all characters at once.

```
import time

def delay_print(a):
    for i in a:             
        print(i ,end = "")
        time.sleep(0.3)
    
delay_print("om")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The print call needs `flush` to be set to True, otherwise the output is buffered and printed at the end, as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608229/what-does-prints-flush-do).

```
import time

def delay_print(a): 
    for i in a:
        print(i, end = "", flush = True)
        time.sleep(0.3)
    print()

delay_print("om")
```

Output (After a second):

```
om
```