# Replace the printed line above with a different value

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
import time

def exitpro(t):
    a=0    
    while t>=0:
        timer="Loading "+"."*((a%3)+1)
        print(timer,end='\r')
        
        time.sleep(1)
        t-=1
        a+=1

    t=int(input("enter time in seconds "))
    exitpro(int(t))
```

I am doing this on jupyter notebook.
I want to print something like "loading." then after one sec "loading.." then "loading..." then again "loading.". But when I run this it prints till 3 dots and then prints the loading with one dot overlapping the loading with 3 dots, so it looks like the program is stuck at loading with 3 dots. Basically, it does not clear the above line, rather prints over it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\r` doesn't clear the line. It simply moves the cursor to the start of the line. You need to actually clear the line, either by explicitly clearing it before you write `Loading.`, or by writing `Loading.`   (notice the extra spaces after the period) to overwrite the extra periods.

```
import time

def exitpro(t):
    a=0    
    while t>=0:
        dotcount = (a % 3) + 1
        timer="Loading" + "." * dotcount + " " * (3 - dotcount)
        print(timer, end='\r', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
        t-=1
        a+=1

t=int(input("enter time in seconds "))
exitpro(t)
```

`flush=True` forces the output to print immediately instead of [waiting to be buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608229/what-does-prints-flush-do).

Comment: what does the flush parameter of print do?

Comment: It forces the output to print immediately instead of [waiting to be buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608229/what-does-prints-flush-do). @ChandravoBhattacharya