# Doing print("Enter text: ", end="") sys.stdin.readline() does not work properly in Python-3

Tags: python, sys

Something weird happened when i did this

```py
import sys

print("Enter text: ", end="")
sys.stdin.readline()
```

Output:

```
<input>
Enter text:
```

*(Here, `<input>` (excluding quotation marks means that input happened on that line))*

Why does the code run as though my code was

```py
import sys

sys.stdin.readline()
print("Enter text: ", end="")
```

(Debian/Ubuntu, Python-3.8.10)

Any reason(s) for this?

Comment: @Eugenij answer is correct. I want to add that you can use the built in `input` function for what you are doing here. The 3 lines of code would become: `input("Enter text: ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that `stdout` hasn't flushed before you enter your input.

Try this

```
import sys

print("Enter text: ", end="")
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdin.readline()
```

```
> Enter text: 123
```

Comment: Or you could do ```print("Enter text: ", flush=True, end="") sys.stdin.readline()```

Comment: @Allearthstuffs Great communty-sense to help and comment on other answers ️ Try your own answer, it is exactly the way to flush.

Answer (score 1):

#### When is flushed

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608229/what-does-prints-flush-do#15608332) explains the reason for flushing as *newline*:

> Normally output to a file or the console is buffered, with text output at least **until** you **print a newline**. The flush makes sure that any output that is buffered goes to the destination.

#### Why this print does not flush

In your statement `print("Enter text: ", end="")` you neither force the flush, nor print newline - instead `end` parameter was overridden (default was `\n` new line). Thus the specified text is printed to buffer only and not yet flushed to console.

#### How to force flush

Built-in function [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) has a parameter named `flush` which default is `False`:

> **`print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`**
>
> [..]
> Whether the output is buffered is usually determined by file, but if the `flush` keyword argument is true, the stream is forcibly flushed.

#### See also

- [How can I flush the output of the print function (unbuffer python output)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function-unbuffer-python-output#230774)
- [How to overwrite the previous print to stdout in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python)
- [What does print()'s `flush` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608229/what-does-prints-flush-do#15608332)
- Delft Stack: [Flush Print Output in Python](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-print-flush/), tutorial

Comment: So, when you do ```print("text")``` it flushes ```sys.stdout``` when the output stream or python interpreter reaches a newline, but when you do ```print("text", end="")``` the output stream or python interpreter does not detect the newline, so is just added to memory (buffer), and then ```sys.stdin.readline()``` returns a newline, then the output stream is flushed and you see ```text``` in the console . . .

Comment: @Allearthstuffs: Exactly, as far as I suppose, that newline from `readline()` effects the flushing. The `print("text")` uses default argument `end = '\n'` which wraps on console and effects flushing, while your `print("text", end="")` does not wrap and thus not flushes.