# Python subprocess not printing real time

Tags: python, python-3.x

test.py

```
import time

for x in range(0, 10, 1):

    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
```

`python test.py` prints real time i.e a number every second

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Now, I wanted to run `test.py` in another script called `run.py` via subprocess like below

run.py

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    'python test.py',
    stdout=PIPE,
    stderr=STDOUT,
    shell=True,
    encoding="utf-8",
    errors="replace",
    universal_newlines=True,
    text=True,
    bufsize=1,
)

while (realtime_output := proc.stdout.readline()) != "" or proc.poll() is None:
    print(realtime_output.strip(), flush=True)
```

when I run `python run.py`, the output is not real time (no number being printed every second)

Strangely, if i modify the code in `test.py` to `print(x, flush=True)` then `python run.py` prints every second

Is there a way to have real time output via `subprocess` in `run.py` without modifying `test.py` print statement?

Comment: this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608229/what-does-prints-flush-do

Comment: check out : [catching stdout in realtime from subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606795/catching-stdout-in-realtime-from-subprocess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bufsize=1` is changing the *input* buffer in the parent process's `proc.stdout` file handle. It doesn't affect the child process's *output* buffer in any way. And when Python's `stdout` is connected to a pipe, rather than a terminal, it automatically goes to block buffering mode.

Change `test.py` to use `print(x, flush=True)` and it will flush the output buffer on each `print`, whether connected to terminal, file, or pipe, and your work to disable the buffering in the parent process will take effect as expected.

Alternatively, change the run of the child process to pass `-u` to `python` to make it unbuffered, e.g. `'python -u test.py'`. That will disable output buffering entirely, removing the need for `flush=True` (but it would make programs that only need `flush=True` *sometimes*, but write out a lot without it, run much slower).

---

As a side-note: There's almost never a reason to use `shell=True` (the only time you can/should use it is if no components of the command line come from untrusted data sources, e.g. the user, and you need to use a shell built-in and/or shell metacharacters, and you're sure you're not using any such metacharacters by accident). Your child process would avoid an unnecessary layer of shell wrapping (that could introduce additional buffering complications), by changing `'python test.py'` to `['python', 'test.py']` (`['python', '-u', 'test.py']` for unbuffered output), and removing `shell=True,`, and everything should run more efficiently and more safely.

You can also drop `universal_newlines=True,`, as `text=True` means *exactly* the same thing; if you're only supporting versions of Python that allow `text=True`, then `universal_newlines=True` is useless to you.

Comment: i went with "python -u test.py" approach. thank you